# XenServer "Software 3D" acceleration, how to assign more vram?

Tags: xenserver

I build a Proof-of-concept on VMWare Workstation for a streaming service, it works very good. Now I'm trying to build the same thing in XenServer.

In my POC I use software accelerated graphics, with 800MB VRam and 3D accelerations enabled.

- How can I get the same results in XEN?
- In VMWare workstation, is vram (Named: Graphics memory) on the host
  the actual ram from the GPU or is it simulated and stored in ram?
- If it is not possible in XenServer, is it possible in VMWare ESXi?

I'm reading online on this topic for very long 10+hours, and I can't find the right answers.

I do understand using a dedicated card like NVidia Grid is going to work as well, but in my POC I did use software accelerated graphics and it is working fine. And I want some answers before I consider buying one of those. Because in the end, if I can run this on windows 7 and VMWare workstation, I better use this as a hyper-visor instead of xen/esxi and a 1K$+ GPU, I guess.

Extra info:

- I will probably run 3-7 VM's using this setup.
- On my Windows PC with VMware workstation I have a high-end GPU.